# Why don't my materials reflect HDR images?

Tags: hdri

When I load a HDR into my scene and set rougness to 0 a material it don´t reflect the HDR image. It´s like it take the light info but don´t reflect the imagen.

[image]

The left material have metallic 1 and rougness 0. The right one have metallic 0 and rougness 0.

I tried with Eevee and Cycles.

Am I missing some settings?

Regards.

Comment: Can you add a closer image of the sphere?Are you using the default HDRi in the material preview?Try increasing the metallic value to 1

Comment: I downloaded the HDRi from https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=kiara_1_dawn

Comment: are you in material preview mode?That is not how a sphere with matallic 1 and roughness 0 should look like

Comment: Sorry I'm new in Blender ¿where is material preview mode? Thank you.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Ay5HH4d.jpg-Check this out .Area marked in blue is the material preview mode..and that's how the sphere must look like

Comment: In material preview mode and rendered mode the metallic material turns black.

Comment: That's weird. Sorry,I can't find a solution to your problem.Try sharing your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug with Intel HD 4000 GPUs. It has been fixed in 2.90. Please try that.

- https://developer.blender.org/T75943
- https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: I test it with version 2.90 and the sphere now looks ok. Thanks a lot!