# Water Volume Density Changes 3D View Port

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a liquid in blender, and when setting the volume density it changes the color of my view port entirely.
[image]

Comment: Hi there :) Can you share your .blend file. Thanks

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 How do I share it via the comments?

Comment: Upload it either in the ggogle drive here-https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Just edit your question and add the file

Comment: It says the file can't be bigger than 30MB. @Nxdhin2005

Comment: Then try uploading in Google drive and create a sharable link...I guess it is a bug. Not sure though

Comment: I forgot mediafire was a thing, and I don't know how to use google drive uploads since I never used google drive. Here is the link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/mcm1wv01s1dqwc1/Cup.blend/file

Comment: I don't experience any issue while using your file even i added in a volume absorption node in the materials preview mode . It is a bug... In the rendered view however I guess you wont have such problems. Materials preview mode has many bugs in certain hardwares. For example see this qn- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186618/why-dont-my-materials-reflect-hdr-images?noredirect=1#comment312757_186618

Comment: You can complain your issue at- https://developer.blender.org .Also try using the latest version of blender.

Comment: I am using the steam version, and it doesn't show that it has any updates. Also I will be sure to report the problem there if it isn't already.